# How to use io.read to read a number

Tags: input, lua

I'm a Lua beginner and don't know how to properly use `io.read` and such.
 I'm working on something very simple and I wanted to replace the `age = 18` statement to something that can get the input from the user, asking them to say their age.

Instead of this:

```
age = 18

if age >= 18 and age <=80 then
    print("You may enter!")
else
    print("You are not allowed in, sorry!")
end
```

I want this:

```
print("What's your age?")
io.read(ONLY ACCEPTS NUMBERS AND IS USED TO COMPARE WITH AGE REQUIREMENTS BELOW)

if age >= 18 and age <=80 then
    print("You may enter!")
else
    print("You are not allowed in, sorry!")
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attempt to convert a variable to a number using [`tonumber()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) and then check the boolean value of that variable.

```
print("What's your age?")
local age = tonumber(io.read())

if age and age >= 18 and age <= 80 then
    print("You may enter!")
else
    print("You are not allowed in, sorry!")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Lua interpreter opens [stdin, stdout, and stderr](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) for you. You can read a number using `io.read` and as the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read) describes, you can use the format `n` to indicate you want to read an integer or float.

```
local age = io.stdin:read 'n'
if age then
  -- age is a number
else
  -- age is nil
end
```